# SQLite and PostgreSql longtext

Tags: sqlite, postgresql, migration

Does anyone know how to change a column in SQLite and PostgreSQL to LONGTEXT?

I have done so in MySQL successfully with:
"ALTER TABLE projects MODIFY description LONGTEXT;"

But this clause doesn't seem to work on SQLite. I tried hard to find documentation on PostgreSQL, but that site's format really makes people puke. SQLite's website is better but the only command I find relevant, alter table, doesn't seem to support changing column data type at all. ( infact, it doesn't even allow changing column name!!!)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PostgreSQL, see the doc [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/ddl-alter.html#AEN2593) (e.g., `ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_col text`).

The [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) doc states

> SQLite supports a limited subset of ALTER TABLE. The ALTER TABLE command in SQLite allows the user to rename a table or to add a new column to an existing table. It is not possible to rename a column, remove a column, or add or remove constraints from a table.

And I suppose changing the datatype of the column is out of scope. Probably to support this, you will need to do a `SELECT * INTO ...` followed by `DROP TABLE ...` and then create the table and run `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM ...`

Comment: Okay, I am going with your approach, and thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, PostgreSQL does not have a limit on blobs, so don't worry.

SQLite3, apparently, doesn't care about the column type in this case (i.e. TEXT is the same as LONGTEXT)

Comment: SQLite *does* support ADD COLUMN.  You can't remove columns, though.

Comment: Sqlite supports both, I think.//It is much better than mssql.

Comment: SQLite definitely does not support removing columns.
Comparing SQLite to MySQL is like comparing a family car to a Ferrari lol

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in declaring a `LONGTEXT` column in SQLite.  All type names with `TEXT` or `CHAR` or `CLOB` in them are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what problem you have with [Postresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/index.html), it's  quite good IMO.

To change a column datatype, [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/ddl-alter.html#AEN2593) is the syntax.

Postgres supports arbitrary long strings (well, up to 2 GB or so) with the [TEXT datatype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/datatype-character.html).

Comment: I must say that finding relevant things in a manual, any manual, has a   lot to do with how familiar you are with it. Documentation like PrototypeJS, Rails, Ruby, in my opinion, even with little experience, one can quickly find what he needs.  Well, okay, I first went to postgresql's site for documentation, there was a clear link. I went there, and went with 8.4 with comment, then maybe b/c I don't know the terms in DB very well, I instinctively looked for something like modifying a table, but found none. But compare it to MySQL, it is much better indeed.

Comment: @Nik Hmmm... personally I hate RDoc but find PostgreSQL's format pretty straight-forward... Different strokes, I suppose.

Comment: Used to detest RDoc as well, then it became a bit more tolerable, and after a few in-the-zone coding session, it became a lot better. 

My prejudice, which now I regret in expressing them so carelessly, came from reading MySQL's documentation. Thinking databases' Now that I am looking at the pages you and Leonbloy mentioned, I must say it's looking great. 

I think it's me who doesn't know "Data Definition" is where you can dig up what I asked about.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't be designing databases without a familiarity with the terms?  Using MySQL obviously doesn't count.